# How to change the repository location for a pipeline in Azure Pipelines

Tags: github, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have imported a repository from BitBucket to GitHub. How can I point the existing pipeline in Azure Pipelines to the new repository location? The UI has failed me so far.

Comment: That UI is very weird.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Simplest way is to create a new pipeline, link it to the github repo and point it to the existing yaml file.

But there is a way to retarget the existing pipeline.

- Edit the pipeline
- In the upper right corner open the <kbd>...</kbd> menu
- Pick the <kbd>⚡ Triggers</kbd> option
- Click the YAML tab
- Click the <kbd>Get Sources</kbd> option
- Reconfigure the source repo

[image: Step by step ideo of the above steps.]

Comment: Awesome! I had a feeling there was a way, but it was not obvious to me that the source selection was tucked away under the "Triggers" option.

Comment: Not obvious is an understatement.

Comment: This option may have disappeared now, at least on private repos and pipelines

Comment: Yeah, definitely hidden and the options are still there

Comment: If this still working, then this solution only aplicates to Classic Editor, not for YAML pipelines

Comment: @GasparZanini Not sure why you'd say so, I just verified and the above is still true for YAML and Classic.

Comment: @jessehouwing yes, you are right, my bad. Idk why at the time I couldn't find that option. Thanks for your answer!